# How can i sort by multiple clumn content?

Tags: mysql, sql

player is a database and guild is the Table.
I just want to get a list/table of all guilds, sorted by first ladder_point,win,draw and if ladder_point,win,draw is equal to other content then sort by minimum of loss.

```
select name,ladder_point,win,draw,loss from player.guild order by ladder_point desc;
+--------------+--------------+-----+------+------+
| name         | ladder_point | win | draw | loss |
+--------------+--------------+-----+------+------+
| Bums         |        19000 |   9 |    1 |    6 |
| D2           |        19000 |   0 |    0 |    0 |
| HammerGilde  |        19000 |   9 |    2 |    1 |
| 31er         |        17000 |   0 |    0 |    0 |
| PromieStatus |        16000 |   1 |    0 |    0 |
| Guildwint    |          100 |   0 |    0 |    0 |
| Test         |            0 |   8 |    0 |    7 |
| AFK          |            0 |   0 |    0 |    0 |
+--------------+--------------+-----+------+------+
```

I want to sort by ladder_point and if ladder_point is max=19000 then sort by win, after win, draw and loss.

for example:
the first entry must be

```
+--------------+--------------+-----+------+------+
| name         | ladder_point | win | draw | loss |
+--------------+--------------+-----+------+------+
| HammerGilde  |        19000 |   9 |    2 |    1 |
| Bums         |        19000 |   9 |    1 |    6 |
```

Sorry for my school english, i hope someone can understand this :D

Comment: Just list multiple columns in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: `order by ladder_point desc, win desc, draw desc, loss ASC`

Comment: thank you , you are my hero